# PHP MySQL delete row not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I really can't seem to figure out why this code is breaking at the relevant sections for the delete button code. Can anyone take a swing at what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm hoping it's just syntax but if it's fundamental understanding I'd appreciate some input, because I also need to make this form do a few more of these update functions.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Call Log System</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '*********';
$db_pwd = '********';
$database = 'call_log';
$table = 'Project_Submissions';





if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");
if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

//Display all fields
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");

if (!$result) 
{
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}


//Main Table 
echo "<table border='1px' width='100%'>
<tr>
<th style='font-size:18px;width:20px;'>ID</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Customer Name</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Phone #</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Address</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Time Zone</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>E-mail</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Alt Phone</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Vehicle</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Project Start</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Project Description</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>RDM</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Phone Attempt 1</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Phone Attempt 2</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Phone Attempt 3</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Email Attempt</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Notes</th>
<th style='font-size:18px;'>Received Date</th>
</tr>";


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<tr>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['ID']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'>{$row['First_Name']} {$row['Last_Name']}</td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><a href=\"tel:{$row['Phone']}\">{$row['Phone']}</a></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Street']} {$row['City']} {$row['State_Country']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><div style=\"width:150px\">{$row['Time_Zone']}</div></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><a href=\"mailto:{$row['Email']}?Subject=FantomWorks\" target=\"_top\">{$row['Email']}</a></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Alt_Phone']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Year']} {$row['Make']} {$row['Model']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Project_Start']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;width:500px;'><div style=\"overflow-x:auto; max-height:100px\">{$row['Project_Description']}</div></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Restoration_Decision_Matrix']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>



        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formDelete' id='formDelete' value='Delete' />
        </form>




    </center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><button type=\"submit\" form=\"form1\" value=\"Submit\">Called</button></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><button type=\"submit\" form=\"form1\" value=\"Submit\">Called</button></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><button type=\"submit\" form=\"form1\" value=\"Submit\">Emailed</button></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>Text Area</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Received_Date']}</center></td>
    </tr>";

}

//Check to see if delete button is pressed
if(isset($_POST['formDelete']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
    {
        $ID = $_POST['ID'];
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Project_Submissions WHERE ID ='".$ID."'";);
    }
}   

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [*"Debugging help please"*](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30195963/1) - Sure, here you go. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: First of all do what @Fred -ii says. it's for your betterment. Also change your delete query like this:-$result = $conn->query('DELETE FROM Project_Submissions WHERE ID ='.$row['ID']);

Comment: `WHERE ID ={$row['ID']}");` wrap your variable with `{}` or better way use PDO `WHERE ID = :row_id );` and `bindParam()`

Comment: Error checking is secondary.  The real acid test is rows_affected.  Your code could be technically error free but you could be trying or actually deleting the wrong record. If it is mission critical then you must also ensure the correct record was indeed the one deleted.  Verify the existence (SELECT), then DELETE, then SELECT again for verification.

Comment: You should stop with this mysql. It's deprecated and not supported. Use prepared statements for security reasons. Otherwise, your whole database would be deleted through this code, in a few seconds.

Comment: @Misunderstood - That's actually not what I meant. Even if you are doing this for yourself, you should be still up to date with the functions. It'll increase your experience in future.

Comment: @Misunderstood - I tried to help. But you are actually exactly what your name says. Good luck in deprecated future.

Comment: @Misunderstood I categorically disagree with your comments here. The `mysql_` family of functions are deprecated, and the need to update is sound, important advise to give to anyone, whether their code is personal, intranet, or a major website. In any and all cases, continued use of those deprecated functions constitutes a bug that must be remedied, and what better time to do it then when you're already working on that code? Further, failure to provide such advisories leaves bad practices unchecked for future readers. There is no point in the future that this code is viable.

Comment: @ChrisBaker my point is that such comments negatively impact the user experience and that should be the paramount concern.

Comment: @Misunderstood [citation needed] -- in what circumstance is providing true, sound technical advice a negative experience? It isn't as though Steve called him names or insinuated he is an idiot (both of which you have done to other users, repeatedly). The bottom line is that Steve's comment was benign and helpful, and your hostility was not. Further, Steve's comment was factual and important, where yours was not. At any rate, the situation has been corrected. Good day, sir.

Comment: @halfer To say mysql_ has security vulnerabilities is technically inaccurate. mysqli_ has extended features to thwart security attacks but is no less vulnerable.  It would not be difficult to make a case the mysqli_ being a work in progress is more at risk for future vulnerabilities msql_ being very stable is exempt from security vulnerabilities.   In real life SQL injection is of concern to an infinitesimal number of public sites.  There are very few sites that with content lucrative enough to put them at risk making them a target of security attacks.

Comment: @Misunderstood I have seen you make that claim. Mysqli is no more or less a "work in progress" than any other part of PHP. That few sites are "worth hacking" is no measure; security through obscurity is not security. mysql_ is NOT exempt from vulnerabilities. The greatest risk is from concatenating queries with unsanitized user input, which the mysql_ library lends itself to by lack of paramerization. These vulnerabilities can only be addressed by a change in **practice**, which is what PDO and mysqli serve to enable.

Comment: Searching Meta for "PDO" or "mysql_" shows that this issue has been discussed quite a bit. You'll find the consensus is to encourage users to adopt better practices and use a non-deprecated library. Example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280950/is-telling-about-deprecated-functionality-wanted/280955#280955 or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254075/what-should-we-do-with-questions-using-deprecated-mysql-functions

Comment: Ok. So I understand your points. Unfortunately this is the PHP and MySQL that I know so I'm going to need to use it to get functioning code and then I can attempt to update.

After making all the changes I've updated my post to reflect because it still does not function. It appears the issue is with where I'm putting the
//Check to see if delete button is pressed
if(isset($_POST['formDelete']))
{
 if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
 {
  $ID = $_POST['ID'];
  $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Project_Submissions WHERE ID ='".$ID."'";);
 }
} 

And how I'm using it. Thoughts?

Comment: There's an extra semicolon in your code. `ID ='".$ID."'";); ` should be `ID ='".$ID."'"); `. That is the specific typo. If you turn on error reporting as suggested, you should see that error. On the subject of PDO/mysqli, it **is** PHP and MySql. It is almost exactly the same as you're used to, just a slight difference in the way you connect, and the way you add variables to a query. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a typo -- there is a superfluous semicolon at the end of the string. `ID ='".$ID."'";);`  should be `ID ='".$ID."'");`

Beyond that, your code contains a serious security vulnerability, it is open to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). If someone were to post `3') OR TRUE; --` as the ID field... you just lost every record in that table, because your delete query now applies to every record. That's why it is absolutely critical to sanitize any information that is coming from the user. Most users won't try to break your site, but some will.

The `mysql_*` family of functions is [officially deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) (see the red notice?). That means it isn't being updated, and any new code should stop using it. The alternatives are PDO or Mysqli, both of which are very similar to what you're already using. The only new thing you have learn is parameterized statements!

Here is how to replace the deprecated mysql_* functions with PDO, and how to check your query for errors.

First, we'll establish the database connection. This replaces the `mysql_connect` stuff:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$database , $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Next, we'll prepare the statement using parameters:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('
    DELETE FROM 
        Project_Submissions 
    WHERE 
        ID = :id
');
```

That `:id` part of the query is called a parameter. Before you can execute the statement, you have to tell PDO what value should go there. You do so by binding a value to the parameter. That's a fancy way of saying "tell PDO what goes there" -- PDO will take care of sanitizing the value.

So, next, we'll execute the statement AND bind the parameters, all at once:

```
$statement->execute(array(
    'id'=>$_POST['ID']
));
```

Now, if you want to ensure something was actually deleted, you can use `$statement->rowCount()` -- it will tell you how many rows were affected.

Putting it all together:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$database , $db_user, $db_pass);
$statement = $pdo->prepare('
    DELETE FROM 
        Project_Submissions 
    WHERE 
        ID = :id
');
$statement->execute(array(
    'id'=>$_POST['ID']
));
```

Query safety is an important subject, whether you're just learning, or an old salt trying to figure out what these darn kids are talking about. Moving forward, it is vital that you keep this in mind any time you write an SQL query.

**Documentation**

- `PDO` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php
- `PDO::prepare` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
- `PDOStatement::execute` - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: THANK YOU for the education!

Now THAT was a helpful post. Thanks again!

Comment: Minor nitpick, I think `mysql_query()` cannot run two queries, and so the `DROP` would not work. However, you're quite right to encourage the OP not to risk it. And of course the `DELETE` is still open to truncation.

Comment: @halfer You're right -- I updated the answer to include a more realistic example. The "Bobby Tables" example I showed, dropping a different table, is easy to throw out there, but not technically true. Thanks for helping to improve the answer! :)

Comment: @new2programming No problem! For an idea, most people make a database wrapper, so you don't have to write all that stuff. Here is a **sample** PDO wrapper class, it gives you a cleaner API. Check the docblock at the top for some use examples, and be warned, this isn't "final" code... you need to test this carefully before using it in a live project. This is a rough base of what I use in my own projects: https://gist.github.com/GRMule/d2f9c42f2a9b39080ee5

Comment: @new2programming: if you would like to see a full project demo using PDO, have a look at the links in my profile. I have a free tutorial that walks the reader through several chapters to build a web app.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $conn->query("DELETE FROM Project_Submissions WHERE ID =$row['ID']");
```

I don't see where $row['ID'] has yet been set. It looks like right above that statement you set the ID of the row you want deleted to $quoteid.

If that's the case you'll instead want to say:

```
 $result = $conn->query("DELETE FROM Project_Submissions WHERE ID = $quoteid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Here ya go!

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<tr>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['ID']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'>{$row['First_Name']} {$row['Last_Name']}</td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><a href=\"tel:{$row['Phone']}\">{$row['Phone']}</a></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Street']} {$row['City']} {$row['State_Country']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><div style=\"width:150px\">{$row['Time_Zone']}</div></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><a href=\"mailto:{$row['Email']}?Subject=FantomWorks\" target=\"_top\">{$row['Email']}</a></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Alt_Phone']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Year']} {$row['Make']} {$row['Model']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Project_Start']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;width:500px;'><div style=\"overflow-x:auto; max-height:100px\">{$row['Project_Description']}</div></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Restoration_Decision_Matrix']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>



        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formDelete' id='formDelete' value='Delete' />
        </form>




    </center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><button type=\"submit\" form=\"form1\" value=\"Submit\">Called</button></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><button type=\"submit\" form=\"form1\" value=\"Submit\">Called</button></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center><button type=\"submit\" form=\"form1\" value=\"Submit\">Emailed</button></center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>Text Area</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Received_Date']}</center></td>
    </tr>";

}

//Check to see if delete button is pressed
if(isset($_POST['formDelete']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
    {
        $ID = $_POST['ID'];
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Project_Submissions WHERE ID ='".$ID."'");
    }
}   

?>
</body>
</html>
```